# I want to partition my disk

Tags: partitioning

I recently installed ubuntu 14.10 but I forgot to partition my drive. I need a separate partition for the OS and and my media files. Do i have to renistall ubuntu or can it be done separately? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Search for Gparted in the Unity Dash and use it to resize your partitions. Please consider searching first, though. There are many tutorials on Google and apparently some threads already made on this website.